# How do I filter Index Action, based on an attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How do I create a route and its corresponding controller method to filter an index action content based on an attribute?

My current routes.rb have:

```
resources :parties
resources :organizations, controller: 'parties', type: 'Organization' 
resources :people, controller: 'parties', type: 'Person'
```

When I need to filter only customer parties I run the query:

```
Party.joins(:party_relationships).where(party_relationships: {relation:"customer"})
```

How do I create a route to let the controller knows that I have to filter only customer parties, while keeping my routes RESTful?

Thanks in advance,

Regards,
Leandro

More information on current models:

**Party**

```
class Party < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :party_relationships
   has_many :second_parties, :through => :party_relationships
   scope :organizations, -> { where(type: 'Organization') } 
   scope :people, -> { where(type: 'Person') } 

    def self.types
      %w(Organization Person)
    end
end
```

**Organization**

```
class Organization < Party
end
```

**Person**

```
class Person < Party
end
```

**PartyRelationship**

```
class PartyRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :party, :class_name=>'Party'
  belongs_to :second_party, :class_name => 'Party'
  enum relation: [ :customer, :supplier, :employee ]
end
```

Comment: Why it was downvoted? Please let me know what was wrong with my question. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not the one to have downvoted, but I guess the problem is that you are not giving details of your work, it is an opinion based question. Please, read the directives as to what a question should look like.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @RubyRacer. I was really asking to try to improve my question. I just edited it.

Comment: I think you should be looking on a variant of `simple table inheritance`... And create sub-models with their responding controllers... This is actually a good question...

Comment: I´m already using STI on the party model for "organizations" and "people". But I´m not sure how this would work for the relationships between them, since any of them can be customers,  suppliers, or both at the same time. The new STI you´re suggesting would be on the Relationship model itself?

Comment: I'm not deep into it, but my approach would be to filter separate models for custommers, suppliers and both... Not sure how I would do it though, sorry...